# two optional arguments in maven command: "-fn" v.s "-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true", any difference?

Tags: java, maven, build

I looked at the "mvn --help", it says -fn means "NEVER fail the build, regardless                              of project result", what does it mean exactly? does it have the same effect as in "-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true"?

I tried both in the mvn command, ironically the command (mvn clean install) with "NEVER fail" option ends with a "build failure" result while the command with "-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true" ends with a successful build.

Anyone can have a clear explanation?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-fn is for multimodule build, where if one fails, it will still go ahead for the next one

-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true will run the tests but ignore results

-e would give you more info about the exceptions, but unlike -X it will not spit out too much debug info

you can combine all 3, I generally do